# Docusaurus links navigate to other pages but not to specific anchors

Tags: docusaurus

In a folder structure like this:

```
|- docs
    |- folder
        |- file_1.md
        |- file_2.md
```

I have links like this:

```
In file_1.md: [File 2 Anchor](file_2.md#file-2-anchor)
In file_2.md: [File 1 Anchor](file_1.md#file-1-anchor)
```

Neither .md file has a slug.

In docusaurus.config:

```
url: 'https://web.<mysite>.ca ',
baseUrl: '/docs/training/dev/',
```

The links work on localhost (using the same baseUrl) navigating to the correct page and anchor. The published links navigate to the correct page but not the anchor -- for any anchor type -- and always jump to the top of the target page

Both the local and published links resolve the same, for example as:

```
<baseURL>/docs/training/dev/docs/folder/file_1#file-1-anchor
```

The links always work locally using relative or absolute paths but the result is always the same for the published links. Seems there is something more to how the links are being resolved.

Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The links must not include the extension of the file (`.md`, `.mdx`), so change

```
file_1.md: [File 2 Anchor](file_2.md#file-2-anchor)
file_2.md: [File 1 Anchor](file_1.md#file-1-anchor)
```

to

```
file_1.md: [File 2 Anchor](file_2#file-2-anchor)
file_2.md: [File 1 Anchor](file_1#file-1-anchor)
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

I tested here, with the following files. To test it, put them in the same directory (doesn't mater wich).

`file1.md`

```
# File 1

Sample test

## Anchor 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in lobortis nisl, quis lacinia elit. Fusce ornare condimentum ligula ut vehicula. Curabitur vehicula neque vitae magna lobortis malesuada. Curabitur porttitor justo lorem, eget blandit arcu euismod eu. Praesent eu risus tincidunt risus rutrum aliquet. Fusce scelerisque, nibh vel porta maximus, ligula libero feugiat lectus, sit amet ornare lectus mauris sed quam. Fusce ut dui laoreet dolor porta semper nec dapibus orci. Sed quis ultricies massa, faucibus porttitor sapien. Sed accumsan laoreet eleifend. Morbi commodo, tellus ac volutpat facilisis, odio arcu venenatis magna, ac cursus nulla ligula ut lacus. Donec lacinia diam ut justo tincidunt, vitae euismod mauris tristique. Morbi iaculis, eros a convallis maximus, nisl risus vehicula odio, eu sodales metus ipsum ac felis. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in lobortis nisl, quis lacinia elit. Fusce ornare condimentum ligula ut vehicula. Curabitur vehicula neque vitae magna lobortis malesuada. Curabitur porttitor justo lorem, eget blandit arcu euismod eu. Praesent eu risus tincidunt risus rutrum aliquet. Fusce scelerisque, nibh vel porta maximus, ligula libero feugiat lectus, sit amet ornare lectus mauris sed quam. Fusce ut dui laoreet dolor porta semper nec dapibus orci. Sed quis ultricies massa, faucibus porttitor sapien. Sed accumsan laoreet eleifend. Morbi commodo, tellus ac volutpat facilisis, odio arcu venenatis magna, ac cursus nulla ligula ut lacus. Donec lacinia diam ut justo tincidunt, vitae euismod mauris tristique. Morbi iaculis, eros a convallis maximus, nisl risus vehicula odio, eu sodales metus ipsum ac felis. 

## Aanchor TWO

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in lobortis nisl, quis lacinia elit. Fusce ornare condimentum ligula ut vehicula. Curabitur vehicula neque vitae magna lobortis malesuada. Curabitur porttitor justo lorem, eget blandit arcu euismod eu. Praesent eu risus tincidunt risus rutrum aliquet. Fusce scelerisque, nibh vel porta maximus, ligula libero feugiat lectus, sit amet ornare lectus mauris sed quam. Fusce ut dui laoreet dolor porta semper nec dapibus orci. Sed quis ultricies massa, faucibus porttitor sapien. Sed accumsan laoreet eleifend. Morbi commodo, tellus ac volutpat facilisis, odio arcu venenatis magna, ac cursus nulla ligula ut lacus. Donec lacinia diam ut justo tincidunt, vitae euismod mauris tristique. Morbi iaculis, eros a convallis maximus, nisl risus vehicula odio, eu sodales metus ipsum ac felis. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in lobortis nisl, quis lacinia elit. Fusce ornare condimentum ligula ut vehicula. Curabitur vehicula neque vitae magna lobortis malesuada. Curabitur porttitor justo lorem, eget blandit arcu euismod eu. Praesent eu risus tincidunt risus rutrum aliquet. Fusce scelerisque, nibh vel porta maximus, ligula libero feugiat lectus, sit amet ornare lectus mauris sed quam. Fusce ut dui laoreet dolor porta semper nec dapibus orci. Sed quis ultricies massa, faucibus porttitor sapien. Sed accumsan laoreet eleifend. Morbi commodo, tellus ac volutpat facilisis, odio arcu venenatis magna, ac cursus nulla ligula ut lacus. Donec lacinia diam ut justo tincidunt, vitae euismod mauris tristique. Morbi iaculis, eros a convallis maximus, nisl risus vehicula odio, eu sodales metus ipsum ac felis. 

## Another anchor With more Text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in lobortis nisl, quis lacinia elit. Fusce ornare condimentum ligula ut vehicula. Curabitur vehicula neque vitae magna lobortis malesuada. Curabitur porttitor justo lorem, eget blandit arcu euismod eu. Praesent eu risus tincidunt risus rutrum aliquet. Fusce scelerisque, nibh vel porta maximus, ligula libero feugiat lectus, sit amet ornare lectus mauris sed quam. Fusce ut dui laoreet dolor porta semper nec dapibus orci. Sed quis ultricies massa, faucibus porttitor sapien. Sed accumsan laoreet eleifend. Morbi commodo, tellus ac volutpat facilisis, odio arcu venenatis magna, ac cursus nulla ligula ut lacus. Donec lacinia diam ut justo tincidunt, vitae euismod mauris tristique. Morbi iaculis, eros a convallis maximus, nisl risus vehicula odio, eu sodales metus ipsum ac felis. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in lobortis nisl, quis lacinia elit. Fusce ornare condimentum ligula ut vehicula. Curabitur vehicula neque vitae magna lobortis malesuada. Curabitur porttitor justo lorem, eget blandit arcu euismod eu. Praesent eu risus tincidunt risus rutrum aliquet. Fusce scelerisque, nibh vel porta maximus, ligula libero feugiat lectus, sit amet ornare lectus mauris sed quam. Fusce ut dui laoreet dolor porta semper nec dapibus orci. Sed quis ultricies massa, faucibus porttitor sapien. Sed accumsan laoreet eleifend. Morbi commodo, tellus ac volutpat facilisis, odio arcu venenatis magna, ac cursus nulla ligula ut lacus. Donec lacinia diam ut justo tincidunt, vitae euismod mauris tristique. Morbi iaculis, eros a convallis maximus, nisl risus vehicula odio, eu sodales metus ipsum ac felis.
```

`file2.md`

```
# File 2 (links)

[anchor 1](file1#Anchor-1)

[anchor 2](file1#Aanchor-TWO)

[anchor 3](file1#Another-anchor-With-more-Text)
```

Comment: Thanks. When I remove the .md extensions, the published links resolve as ```<baseURL>/docs/training/dev/docs/folder/file_1/#file-1-anchor```, with a slash in front of the # symbol and the behaviour is the same -- localhost works but published links jump to the top of the target page.

Comment: Actually, the links like ```[File 1 Anchor]``` and the actual anchors are published as ```<baseURL>/docs/folder/file_1#file-1-anchor```. Clicking on the anchors puts exactly that in the address bar and jumps to the anchor but the links still do not navigate to the anchors. If I manually enter the addresses with a ```/``` in front of the```#``` I can navigate to anchors as expected. Looks like the break is that the slash is not being included.

Comment: I updated the answer with a simple example, try it to see if works, please. Also, note that the spaces are replaced by a dash, and the case — I think that the case is insensitive, but I prefer to keep them equals.

Comment: Turns out the version field of package.json in my commit got corrupted. The bad linking was the only bad behaviour I had encountered so it seemed like a problem with linking when it wasn't. After some other bad behaviour popped up I found the bad .json. The correct format for the local links _does_ use the .md extension like ```[Anchor X](./file_X.md#anchor-x)``` and the extension is removed in the build as documented here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-markdown-features. I'm surprised the production build worked at all. It was quite a puzzle. Thanks for the consult!

Comment: Good to known! And, nice catch.

Comment: You might be able to answer your own question, @Schemer, and then people coming to this question can see that answer. Might be useful for some folks.